# firebase anonymous auth with cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use firebase anonymous auth + firebase cloud function. The idea is that I have a piece of code that should be run in the google cloud.

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
  .then(() => {
    // Here I call firebase cloud function
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

Now, all good, but the actual problem is that malicious user can call my google cloud function the same way and he will be able to execute it, which means too bad for me. Basically, google cloud function should be executable only from my website, not by anyone else. I was advised to use firebase, otherwise what I was doing is simply calling the function in the front-end code.

Does firebase offer the workaround/solution to this problem ? NOTE: I can't really distinguish users from my interface, because with whatever I distinguish, malicious user can get those information anyways.

The reason I am doing all these is that there's a piece of code that only my front-end has to execute and I don't want to implement my back-end service for just this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) sound like a perfect solution for your needs. It allows access to your Firebase Project only from your allowed Apps and Web pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great advice. Though, I might ask, how does google know that cloud function was not called from my app, but from another app ? because anything can be changed by malicious user - even origin.

Comment: I mean, I am planning on using it from front-end, so whatever and however I initialize the firebase and activate firebase app check, hacker will do the same

Comment: He can't do it withou having access to your Firebase Project. By that I mean accessing your Firebase project console.

Comment: Pretty good stuff ... I guess google has lots of checks with this to work, because for example, if it only checks with origin, then origin spoofing is possible

Comment: Am I correct about what I said in my last comment ? I mean he can still copy/paste the initialization code + calling the cloud function code... since origin spoofing is possible, I thought using firebase would also be exploitable..

Comment: You could do the origin check before AppCheck. Did you check the documentation of from the Link I wrote? There is everything ecplained in detail. But yes AppCheck is made for such cases where for examole the database rules need to be open for everyone.

Comment: origin check can be exploitable. the link doesn't explain how it figures out that the request made from my app succeeds and request made from another app fails.

Comment: It stands very clear that it uses reCAPTCHA v3 and `A Firebase service protected by App Check only accepts requests accompanied by a current, valid App Check token.`